# How many missiles does it take to kill the final boss in SpaceChem?

Tags: spacechem

I have a working solution, but it leaves two waste carbon atoms for every missile, which I currently fuse continuously in a corner of one reactor, so I can only fire 8 missiles before I run out of elements in the periodic table :/ I'm hoping I can get away with this inelegant solution if I'm careful/lucky with the asteroids :)

Answer (score 2):

My solution took 10 direct missile hits. Looks like you may be headed back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Explaining what your solution was could be helpful.

Comment: Helpful, certainly! But it would also be a spoiler, and that's not what Enigmaster asked for. If you want full solutions, check youtube or spacechem.net.